# Laravel - Database query on default null date

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I was trying to get some records of a table, which has a column 'UpdateDate' with default value NULL. I need to check if a record exists that either 'UpdateDate' is not today or 'UpdateDate' is NULL. The query I built is as follows:

```
DB::table('Users')
->where('id', '=', '10')
->where(function($query) {  
    $query->where('UpdateDate','<>',date("Y-m-d"))->orWhere('UpdateDate','is','NULL'); })
->exists()
```

It didn't work as expected. How should I modify it? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change you query to this

```
DB::table('Users')
->where('id', '=', '10')
->where(function($query) {  
    $query->where('UpdateDate','<>', date("Y-m-d"))
    ->orWhereNull('UpdateDate'); 
})
->exists();
```

If you have `UpdateDate` `date` as **datatype**.

If you have `timestamp` or `datetime` as **datatype** then change to this

```
DB::table('Users')
->where('id', '=', '10')
->where(function($query) {  
    $query->whereBetween('UpdateDate',[date("Y-m-d 00:00:00"), date("Y-m-d 23:59:59")])
    ->orWhereNull('UpdateDate'); 
})
->exists();
```